# finding missing numbers from sequence after getting sequenuce from a string?

Tags: oracle

I have a millions of string record like this one with 310 types of them that have different format to get sequence,year,month and day from..

the script will get the sequence,year,month and day... now I want a Pl/Sql that will get the max and min value number of the sequence and find the missing number where is year and month are for example 14 - 06 how ??

Comment: It's absolutely not clear what you are trying to do. Please explain more detailed. And what does it mean: _insert into dual_???

Comment: @simon 
pls read my post update.. hope its clear now

Comment: You can't insert anything into DUAL. If you try an insert, you'll get `insufficient privileges`. Out of curiosity, I tried doing that long time ago :)

Comment: You cursor is fetching a single column `ename`, but you're referring to `List_ENAME_cur.filename`. You'll get an error right there!

Comment: sry thats was typing error... and i update my post and show u my procedure i want to call i dont know how to link between them and how to find out the max and min value to let my procedure works fine

Comment: @ Incognito ..........................

Comment: possible duplicate of [missing numbers script wont work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900092/missing-numbers-script-wont-work)

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to be looking at `dual` at all here; certainly not attempting to insert. You need to track the highest and lowest values you've seen as you iterate through the loop. based on some of the elements of `ename` representing dates I'm pretty sure you want all your matches to be `0-9`, not `1-9`. You're also referring to the cursor name as you access its fields, instead of the record variable name:

```
  FOR List_ENAME_rec IN List_ENAME_cur loop
    if REGEXP_LIKE(List_ENAME_rec.ENAME,'emp[-][0-9]{4}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{4}[_][G][1]') then 
      V_seq := substr(List_ENAME_rec.ename,5,4);
      V_Year := substr(List_ENAME_rec.ename,10,2);
      V_Month := substr(List_ENAME_rec.ename,13,2);
      V_day := substr(List_ENAME_rec.ename,16,2);

      if min_seq is null or V_seq < min_seq then
        min_seq := v_seq;
      end if;
      if max_seq is null or V_seq > max_seq then
        max_seq := v_seq;
      end if;

    end if;
  end loop;
```

With values in the table of `emp-1111_14_01_01_1111_G1` and `emp-1115_14_02_02_1111_G1`, that reports `max_seq 1115 min_seq 1111`.

If you really wanted to involve dual you could do this inside the loop, instead of the if/then/assign pattern, but it's not necessary:

```
      select least(min_seq, v_seq), greatest(max_seq, v_seq)
      into min_seq, max_seq
      from dual;
```

I have no idea what the procedure is going to do; there seems to be no relationship between whatever you've got in `test1` and the values you're finding.

You don't need any PL/SQL for this though. You can get the min/max values from a simple query:

```
select min(to_number(substr(ename, 5, 4))) as min_seq,
  max(to_number(substr(ename, 5, 4))) as max_seq
from table1
where status = 2
and regexp_like(ename,
  'emp[-][0-9]{4}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{4}[_][G][1]')

   MIN_SEQ    MAX_SEQ
---------- ----------
      1111       1115
```

And you can use those to generate a list of all values in that range:

```
with t as (
  select min(to_number(substr(ename, 5, 4))) as min_seq,
    max(to_number(substr(ename, 5, 4))) as max_seq
  from table1
  where status = 2
  and regexp_like(ename,
    'emp[-][0-9]{4}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{4}[_][G][1]')
)
select min_seq + level - 1 as seq
from t
connect by level <= (max_seq - min_seq) + 1;

       SEQ
----------
      1111 
      1112 
      1113 
      1114 
      1115
```

And a slightly different common table expression to see which of those don't exist in your table, which I think is what you're after:

```
with t as (
  select to_number(substr(ename, 5, 4)) as seq
  from table1
  where status = 2
  and regexp_like(ename,
    'emp[-][0-9]{4}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{4}[_][G][1]')
),
u as (
  select min(seq) as min_seq,
    max(seq) as max_seq
  from t
),
v as (
  select min_seq + level - 1 as seq
  from u
  connect by level <= (max_seq - min_seq) + 1
)
select v.seq as missing_seq
from v
left join t on t.seq = v.seq
where t.seq is null
order by v.seq;

MISSING_SEQ
-----------
       1112 
       1113 
       1114
```

or if you prefer:

```
...
select v.seq as missing_seq
from v
where not exists (select 1 from t where t.seq = v.seq)
order by v.seq;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/58313/1).

---

Based on comments I think you want the missing values for the sequence for each combination of the other elements of the ID (YY_MM_DD). This will give you that breakdown:

```
with t as (
  select to_number(substr(ename, 5, 4)) as seq,
    substr(ename, 10, 2) as yy,
    substr(ename, 13, 2) as mm,
    substr(ename, 16, 2) as dd
  from table1
  where status = 2
  and regexp_like(ename,
    'emp[-][0-9]{4}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{4}[_][G][1]')
),
r (yy, mm, dd, seq, max_seq) as (
  select yy, mm, dd, min(seq), max(seq)
  from t
  group by yy, mm, dd
  union all
  select yy, mm, dd, seq + 1, max_seq
  from r
  where seq + 1 <= max_seq
)
select yy, mm, dd, seq as missing_seq
from r
where not exists (
  select 1 from t
  where t.yy = r.yy
  and t.mm = r.mm
  and t.dd = r.dd
  and t.seq = r.seq
)
order by yy, mm, dd, seq;
```

With output like:

```
YY   MM   DD    MISSING_SEQ 
---- ---- ---- -------------
14   01   01            1112 
14   01   01            1113 
14   01   01            1114 
14   02   02            1118 
14   02   02            1120 
14   02   03            1127 
14   02   03            1128
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5edd2/1).

If you want to look for a particular date you cold filter that (either in `t`, or the first branch in `r`), but you could also change the regex pattern to include the fixed values; so to look for `14 06` the pattern would be `'emp[-][0-9]{4}_14_06_[0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{4}[_][G][1]'`, for example. That's harder to generalise though, so a filter (`where t.yy = '14' and t.mm = '06'` might be more flexible.

---

If you insist in having this in a procedure, you can make the date elements optional and modify the regex pattern:

```
create or replace procedure show_missing_seqs(yy in varchar2 default '[0-9]{2}',
  mm in varchar2 default '[0-9]{2}', dd in varchar2 default '[0-9]{2}') as

  pattern varchar2(80);
  cursor cur (pattern varchar2) is
    with t as (
      select to_number(substr(ename, 5, 4)) as seq,
        substr(ename, 10, 2) as yy,
        substr(ename, 13, 2) as mm,
        substr(ename, 16, 2) as dd
      from table1
      where status = 2
      and regexp_like(ename, pattern)
    ),
    r (yy, mm, dd, seq, max_seq) as (
      select yy, mm, dd, min(seq), max(seq)
      from t
      group by yy, mm, dd
      union all
      select yy, mm, dd, seq + 1, max_seq
      from r
      where seq + 1 <= max_seq
    )
    select yy, mm, dd, seq as missing_seq
    from r
    where not exists (
      select 1 from t
      where t.yy = r.yy
      and t.mm = r.mm
      and t.dd = r.dd
      and t.seq = r.seq
    )
    order by yy, mm, dd, seq;
begin
  pattern := 'emp[-][0-9]{4}[_]'
    || yy || '[_]' || mm || '[_]' || dd
    || '[_][0-9]{4}[_][G][1]';
  for rec in cur(pattern) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(rec.missing_seq, 'FM0000'));
  end loop;
end show_missing_seqs;
/
```

I don't know why you insist it has to be done like this or why you want to use `dbms_output` as you're relying on the client/caller displaying that; what will your job do with the output? You could make this return a `sys_refcursor` which would be more flexible. but anyway, you can call it like this from SQL*Plus/SQL Developer:

```
set serveroutput on
exec show_missing_seqs(yy => '14', mm => '01');

anonymous block completed
1112
1113
1114
```

Comment: thanks but I want to know how to link between my PLscript and procedure 
4example the one that show those records that dont exist in my table 
the output of script will get the seq,year,month,day from string which is
the input of procedure that will find the missing number in sequence where year 2014 or where at year 2014 and month 06 
then print those missing number at the DBMSoutput and that what I want to know How to link between script and procedure... please continue reading next comment...

Comment: continue.. why I want get the missing seq from procedure?
coz I have several types of string like the one u saw i want 2 catch them then call procedure to print out missing number for each string

Comment: @user3304876 - your procedure is looking at a `test1` table that seems to have no relationship with what's in `table1`, is a weird way o looking for missing values, and is broken anyway. Why do you want to do this with a procedure, or even with PL/SQL? What 'input' do you mean - you want to specify that somewhere, or do you want to show the missing values for each year/month/day combination, all in one go?

Comment: @user3304876 - I think my edited answer gets the result you want. But are you fixated on having it done in PL/SQL for some reason? Also is the sequence the first four-digit pattern, or the second one - you seem to have changed that.

Comment: ummm im thinking about simple way like we are already loop across the sequence so can I add an if condition where that min_seq is null then print the previous sequence number +1 ?? please read my post I had update it so can see the last update version of it... thanks

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me. Not sure why a manual loop in a PL/SQL block would be 'simple' compared to a single SQL query. I don't understand what result you want, or how that differs from what I've done. I'm showing the missing values from the sequence. (And if `min_seq` is `null` then `min_seq+1` will also be null).

Comment: In pl i Cant sue sql query so the code above will not work I need away to look on that sequence and print out the missing number with script at frst post with lastest result i came out with ... sry about my bad english maybe thats why u dont understand what I need sry again

Comment: @user3304876 - it may partly be a language problem, yes. You can add sample data and expected output to the question to make it clearer, maybe. Why does it have to be in PL/SQL? You can just use this query in a cursor if you really want to, but I don't understand why an anonymous block would be better than a simple query.

Comment: coz that's daily task I have to do so i wanna create procedure for that and job to lunch it at specific time hope here is away to set a condition to catch those missing number and then print them out i got tired of trying

Comment: what do u mean by t and r? are they tables ? and why sould I create this table ??

Comment: @user3304876 - they are [subquery factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF30048) clauses; also called common table expressions (CTEs). They are not physical tables, they only exist as pseudo-tables within the query. It's the same as as doing `select ... from (select ...))`, but rearranged and easier to read (I think, anyway). They save you doing explicit nested cursor loops. `r` is a recursive CTE in this case, so it requires 11gR2.

Comment: this code not working correctly coz there is existing sequence and its print them as missing for example... some sequence are duplicated but at at same day like 0405 this you may find it at 12-03-14 or 13-03-14 -_-

Comment: and the input is varchar2 and at the substring there is convert to number :S that's will ignore all zeros at left hand

Comment: It's not ignoring the zeros; the sequence is a number so they don't matter. You can do `to_char(seq, 'FM0000') as missing_seq`. I don't understand the dup comment, it's looking within each day.

Comment: but 4me its really matter coz the number format is like that 0001 - 0002 -0003 etc until 9999 so ignoring the lefthand zero well effect procedure result query 0001 am I right ?? or there is misstake at this procedure and its output not correct

Comment: It's comparing numbers internally, and I've already made it add back the leading zero for display. I can't tell if you think it's wrong from looking at it, or if you have data that gives the wrong answer - if so, please put it in an SQL fiddle, and show exacly what you are running, what output you get, and what you expect. In today's question you'd messed up the pattern.

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with that output. It shows the missing values between the highest and lowest. With leading zeroes: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/678b6/12