# missing numbers script wont work?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

This script will get the sequence,year,month and day from the following string... 
then find the missing number from the sequence part like (1111,1112,115,.. etc)
the problem is that the output of this script are not correct does not DBMS the missing numbers

> emp-1111_14_01_01_2141_G1
>
> emp-1112_14_01_01_1612_G1
>
> emp-1115_14_01_01_1109_G1
>
> emp-1116_14_01_01_1315_G1
>
> emp-1118_14_01_01_0910_G2
>
> emp-1121_14_01_01_1105_G1
>
> emp-1111_14_01_01_1120_G2

The output result should be like this

> Missing number 1113
>
> Missing number 1114
>
> Missing number 1117
>
> Missing number 1118
>
> Missing number 1119
>
> Missing number 1120

```
declare 
  v_name          table1.ENAME%TYPE;
  V_seq           NUMBER (4);
  V_Year          number(2);
  V_Month         number (2);
  V_day           number (2);
  max_seq         number(4);
  min_seq         number(4);

  CURSOR List_ENAME_cur IS
  SELECT ENAME from table1
  WHERE status = 2;
begin 

  FOR List_ENAME_rec IN List_ENAME_cur loop
    if REGEXP_LIKE(List_ENAME_cur.ENAME,'emp[-][1-9]{4}[_][1-9]{2}[_][1-9]{2}[_][1-9]{2}[_][0-9]{4}[_][G]["1"]') then 
      V_seq := substr(List_ENAME_cur.ename,5,4);
      V_Year := substr(List_ENAME_cur.ename,10,2);
      V_Month := substr(List_ENAME_cur.ename,13,2);
      V_day := substr(List_ENAME_cur.ename,16,2);


      if min_seq is null or V_seq_FILENAME < min_seq then
        min_seq := V_seq_FILENAME;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Missing number '||min_seq );
      end if;

      if max_seq is null or V_seq_FILENAME > max_seq then
        max_seq := V_seq_FILENAME;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Missing number '||max_seq );
      end if;

    end if;
  end loop;    
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('max_seq '||max_seq||' min_seq '||min_seq);    
end;
```

Comment: For this dataset, what should be the expected result?

Comment: the result should be Missing number 1113,1114,1117,1118,1119,1120

Comment: if condition should should output the number where the value if the loop is numm am I right ???

Comment: I dont find 1118 missing as per the data set. Can you add the correct data set and the expected result to the question?

Comment: This can be easily done in SQL and if it is so dont go to pl sql.

Comment: 1118 is missing coz of G2 at the end of the string.. result output update it to post... and it should be written using PL/sql

Answer (score 0):

See this example

```
WITH ORDH
     AS (SELECT 1111 AS ORDERNO FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1112 AS ORDERNO FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1115 AS ORDERNO FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1116 AS ORDERNO FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1118 AS ORDERNO FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1121 AS ORDERNO FROM DUAL),
     GOT_NEXT_ORDERNO
     AS (SELECT ORDERNO,
                LEAD ( ORDERNO ) OVER (ORDER BY ORDERNO) AS NEXT_ORDERNO
         FROM   ORDH)
SELECT ORDERNO + 1 AS FROM_NO, NEXT_ORDERNO - 1 AS TO_NO
FROM   GOT_NEXT_ORDERNO
WHERE  ORDERNO + 1 <> NEXT_ORDERNO;

   FROM_NO      TO_NO
---------- ----------
      1113       1114
      1117       1117
      1119       1120

3 rows selected.
```

Comment: the above string is just an example of 2 million record that,s wont work out... plus it NOT PL/SQL  thanks